# Using ControlValueAccessor - value is out of sync with two value sources

Tags: angular

I'm building my own custom input fields. I want to use `ControlValueAccessor` to make use of `FormGroup` with `FormControlName` as well as `ngModel`.

Problem is when I have two input fields in one form. Those inputs are out of sync but `FormGroup` value is in sync.

Here is sample app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9krudy

If You change value in input field, it does not reflect on component's value but reflects in `FormGroup` value.

If You change value using `my-input` component ("Change value randomly" button) it changes value in component but not in input. As previous, value in `FormGroup` is changing.

When I change `FormGroup` value using `patchValue` all works as it should.

How to fix my code to always be in sync??
I want to be able to use `my-input` with `ngModel` so passing `FormGroup` and depending on it is not an option.

**EDIT:**

I've discovered that in `Angular` **You cannot have two input fields with the same `formNameControl`**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2sj5g (Ok, You can but they are not in sync). So this question is invalid.

**EDIT: code**

AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        text: new FormControl('text')
    });

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onChange() {
        this.formGroup.get('text')
            .patchValue('New value');
    }
}
```

AppComponentHtml

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input type="text" [formControlName]="'text'">
    <my-input [formControlName]="'text'"></my-input>
</form>
```

MyInputComponent:

```
import {Component, forwardRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-input',
    template: `<hr>
In component
<p>
    <a (click)="onChange()" href="javascript:void(null)">Change value randomly</a>
</p>
Value in component: <b>{{value}}</b>
<hr>`,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyInputComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class MyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    protected _value: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onChange() {
        this.value = Math.random();
    }

    get value(): any {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: any) {
        this._value = value;
        this.propagateChange(this._value);
    }

    writeValue(value: any) {
        console.log('Out from component', value);
        if (value !== undefined) {
            this._value = value;
        }
    }

    propagateChange = (_: any) => {
    };

    registerOnChange(fn) {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put a [mcve] *in the question*, the StackBlitz link should only be supporting information.

Comment: There - question edited

Comment: @piernik, I think must be formControlName="text", NOT [formControlName]="'text'". But It's strange, in the same form you have two fields "text" ???

Comment: It turns out that in Angular I cannot have two field with the same `controlName` : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2sj5g

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

1. Your `my-input` component should include input element inside it's template

   ```
   @Component({
     selector: 'my-input',
     template: `
       <input [value]="value" 
              (change)="onValueChanged($event)" 
              (keyup)="onValueChanged($event)"/>
   ...
   ```

   where `onValueChanged` method is used to set value stored in your component

   ```
   onValueChanged(event) {
     this.value = event.target.value;
   }
   ```
2. You have two form controls with same `formControlName` value. Change it to something else e.g.

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
       Input: <input formControlName="otherInput"/> <br/>
       My input: <my-input formControlName="text"></my-input>
   </form>


   formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
       text: new FormControl('text'),
       otherInput: new FormControl('otherText')
   });
   ```

working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t3qbaz?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: What do I need `input` in `my-input`? I have `setter` for value which update `ngModel` for me.

Comment: Probably there is a way to make it work with input outside of your `my-input` component but then I don't really see a point of creating such component if you still need to use external input.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that in Angular You cannot have two input fields with the same formNameControl: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y2sj5g (Ok, You can but they are not in sync). So this question is invalid.

**Edit:**
This is `Angular's` feature: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10036

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in Angular. But you can do it with a little trick.

Run below function on text value change. This function dumb as it assigns text's value to itself. But it will trigger Angular to re-evaluate the changes to both inputs.

```
formGroup.patchValue({
    text: formGroup.value.text
  });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szwjua?file=app/app.component.ts